# PHP - File cache SQL queries in Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, caching

I'm new at hosting with Google App Engine and haven't got my file caches to work yet any is therefore running a bunch of SQL queries that at least on my last dedicated server made more sense to have file cached.

My questions are:

1. Is it worth file caching on Google App Engine or is there some disadvantages of using a bucket to store TXT files for SQL queries that rarely change but are triggered a couple of times per second?
2. What's the most simple way of printing a file to a bucket in a flexible environment? I've tried just this code but it doesn't work. Am I entering the bucket path correctly and is there something I need to do before, like including some script, adding something to the app.yaml or something?

   file_put_contents("gs://${my-test-project-xxxxxxxx.appspot.com}/cache/hello_caching.txt", "Text to be added");